# Error resolving version for plugin 'spring:boot' from the repositories

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I want to run new project in IntelliJ. And again I have some problems with I think dependencies in pom.xml.

I've tried a lot of stackoverflow topics. Did not work.

```sh
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.5.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.cognifide.homework</groupId>
    <artifactId>homework</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <name>homework</name>
    <description>Desc</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-autoconfigure</artifactId>
        </dependency>   
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

I already tried clean install(after clean install build is succes but when I want to run mvn spring:boot:run I got an erroe), delete m2 folder...
This is console output

```sh
[ERROR] Error resolving version for plugin 'spring:boot' from the repositories [local (/home/michalch/.m2/repository), central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2)]: Plugin not found in any plugin repository -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.plugin.version.PluginVersionResolutionException: Error resolving version for plugin 'spring:boot' from the repositories [local (/home/michalch/.m2/repository), central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2)]: Plugin not found in any plugin repository
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.version.internal.DefaultPluginVersionResolver.selectVersion(DefaultPluginVersionResolver.java:236)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.version.internal.DefaultPluginVersionResolver.resolveFromRepository(DefaultPluginVersionResolver.java:148)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.version.internal.DefaultPluginVersionResolver.resolve(DefaultPluginVersionResolver.java:96)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoDescriptorCreator.resolvePluginVersion(MojoDescriptorCreator.java:280)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoDescriptorCreator.getMojoDescriptor(MojoDescriptorCreator.java:235)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.DefaultLifecycleTaskSegmentCalculator.calculateTaskSegments(DefaultLifecycleTaskSegmentCalculator.java:103)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.DefaultLifecycleTaskSegmentCalculator.calculateTaskSegments(DefaultLifecycleTaskSegmentCalculator.java:83)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:89)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:307)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:193)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:106)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:863)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:288)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:199)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
[ERROR]
```

Any ideas ? Because I have no idea what I am doing wrong :(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

do you want to try 
**mvn spring-boot:run**

Comment: I did dumbest mistake ever and use 
```mvn spring:boot:run
```
instead 
```mvn spring-boot:run
```
I spend on this almost two hours. Thank you so much!

Comment: Funny, lol, I did exactly the same mistake as you @derirative23

Comment: Nowadays, the right command is **mvnw** on Linux.